# Muzzle Velocity of a Bullet out of a Barrel

Tags: kinematics, projectile

We want to know the speed of a bullet, in feet per second, for a given round. We know the weight of the bullet, volume of the casing, amount of gun powder, length of the barrel, and diameter of the barrel.

How do we calculate muzzle Velocity? Is that enough data or do we need more?

Comment: There are published ballistics charts on various bullets.  With a bit of research, you should be able to develop an equation that answers your question.

Comment: @DavidWhite I don't think that I can by just looking at ballistics charts, they have the actual values for fps and then calculate energy, etc. But I want to know if it's possible to derive the fps without doing tests.. if you knew the weight of the bullet and amount of powder, could you reliably predict the round's fps(velocity)

Comment: @Adam12344 probably not without empirical data. I doubt explosions give very precise and reproducible results.

Comment: You are asking about internal ballistics. See for example this Wikipedia link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_ballistics). I only know a bit about ballistics, and not as much about internal ballistics, but I doubt that you have enough information to make a reliable estimate. For example, I believe that propellent burn rate is important in determining how pressure builds up to accelerate the projectile. It is possible you can use the energy and momentum equations to estimate an upper limit for muzzle velocity. A practical result will likely require more detailed analysis and testing.

Comment: At a minimum, energy can be lost to friction, the working of the mechanism (gas blowback, anyone?), and left in the gas ejected from the barrel. That’s a lot of places to mess up a BoTE calculation.

Comment: This is a typical problem of gas dynamics - the piston moves in the channel as the gas expands. It is usually assumed that the powder burns instantly, and the gas expands adiabatically. But we can calculate everything in detail, taking into account the final rate of combustion of gunpowder, shock waves, heat loss, bullet rotation and other effects.

Comment: you will find your answer on a page dealing with gun physics i.e., internal ballistics.

Comment: @Adam12344, IF you could model a gun shot, you would find that there are several variables to consider, and you probably can't calculate them with any certainty.  For example, how fast does the gun powder burn?  Is this rate of burning affected by the age of the gun powder?  What is the pressure in the gun barrel vs. time?  How much friction is involved as the bullet travels down the barrel?  How much kinetic energy goes into rotating the bullet vs. giving it translational velocity?  Do any of these variables change as more rounds are fired?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many variables,I doubt if you could arrive at an accurate figure without empirical data. For a start, the length of the barrel has an important bearing on the muzzle velocity. The nature of the propellant: black powder is seldom used nowadays. The quantity of propellant. The rifling: as well as friction. the rifling converts some of the forward energy into rotational energy. Is the weapon gas operated, recoil operated or bolt action? Are you talking about recoilless rifles (which are not the sort of rifles you can put to your shoulder)? I see you have some of these statistics, but not all.

Comment: When I said you can't put a recoilless rifle to your shoulder,I was forgetting the Swedish made Carl Gustav,which you can put to your shoulder,but you have to keep clear of the venturi. I heard of a soldier who had his shoulder blown off by the blast from the venturi.